# Access to MessageBox.Show default strings

Tags: c#, multilingual, messagebox

I am working on a multi-lingual application. I have an exception that I can get a translated string from:

`MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);` - Window uses a default caption.

I'd like access to buttons and Icon:

`MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, <window default caption>, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);`

Is there a way to access Windows default MessageBox caption?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for this? There are about 2 dozen overloads, so maybe look at a different one?

Comment: MessageBox caption argument is of type string, I really dont think there exists a default caption

Comment: The default caption is default(string) which is ""

Answer (score 0):

The only way to have a MessageBox show with a message, button options and icon is when you also provide a caption with it, as shown by the overload. There is no "default" message caption per say; like Bizhan said, it is just an empty string.

```
// MessageBox.Show(Message, Caption, Buttons, Icon)

MessageBox.Show(String, String, MessageBoxButton, MessageBoxImage)
```

However, you could give it a caption by parsing it the name of the form if that is possible by doing the following:

```
// If you are in the class where your main form is, use this
MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, this.Name, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

// Otherwise, you could simply type the name in
MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Name of WinForm", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
```